# Getting all comments for post by shortcode instagram site

Tags: instagram, graphql

I make requests with Instagram from the browser on the links:

- [https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17852405266163336&variables={"shortcode":"BemdtV0gLAL","first":4500}](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17852405266163336&variables=%7B%22shortcode%22:%22BemdtV0gLAL%22,%22first%22:4500%7D)
- https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?after&first=4500&query_id=17852405266163336&shortcode=BemdtV0gLAL

I receive the document in Json format, in which the total number of comments does not correspond to the number of comments in the list. The comments were checked manually, there are indeed more comments than shown in the document.

Is this the Instagram error? What is the request for a complete list of comments?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TwKP.jpg)